# react native oneSignal Trying to catch error on promptForPushNotificationsWithUserResponse

Tags: react-native, onesignal

Some of my android users have the following error `Could not invoke OneSignal.promptForPushNotificationsWithUserResponse`. I can not reproduce the error, I only see it on Sentry.

I tried to do something like that to prevent it

```
export async function init() {
  try {
    OneSignal.setAppId('xxx');

    try {
      // https://github.com/OneSignal/react-native-onesignal/issues/1449
      OneSignal.promptForPushNotificationsWithUserResponse();
    } catch (error) {
      if (Platform.OS !== 'android') {
        throw error;
      }
      await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.POST_NOTIFICATIONS,
      );
    }

  } catch (error) {
    logError(error);
  }
}
```

But the error is not catch, is it normal ?